pandas - fill missing value from other matching records on multiple columns within same dataframe
I have a dataframe with the following data



RowID
Column 1
Column 2
Column 3
Column 4
Column 5
Column ID




1
A
B
C
D
E
nan


2
A
B
C
D
E
nan


3
A
B
C
D
E
a1234


4
B
C
D
E
F
nan


5
B
C
D
E
F
b2345


6
C
D
E
F
G
c3456


7
C
D
E
F
G
nan



The output I'm looking for



RowID
Column 1
Column 2
Column 3
Column 4
Column 5
Column ID




1
A
B
C
D
E
a1234


2
A
B
C
D
E
a1234


3
A
B
C
D
E
a1234


4
B
C
D
E
F
b2345


5
B
C
D
E
F
b2345


6
C
D
E
F
G
c3456


7
C
D
E
F
G
c3456



I tried using the following code
fill_map = df.dropna(subset=['Column ID'])[['Column 1','Column 2','Column 3','Column 4','Column 5']].drop_duplicates().set_index(['Column 1','Column 2','Column 3','Column 4','Column 5'])['Column ID'].to_dict()

df['Column ID'] = df.groupby(['Column 1','Column 2','Column 3','Column 4','Column 5'])['Column ID'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill'))

This did not work, even existing values were replaced with Nan.
How do I get the expected output ?

groupby then transform with bfill and ffill.
# example df
data = {
    "RowID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    "Column 1": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
    "Column 2": ["B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"],
    "Column 3": ["C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E"],
    "Column 4": ["D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F"],
    "Column 5": ["E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "G", "G"],
    "Column ID": [np.nan, np.nan, "a1234", np.nan, "b2345", "c3456", np.nan],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# solution
df["Column ID"] = (
    df.groupby(df.filter(regex=r"Column \d").columns.tolist())["Column ID"]
    .bfill()
    .ffill()
)

   RowID Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 Column 5 Column ID
0      1        A        B        C        D        E     a1234
1      2        A        B        C        D        E     a1234
2      3        A        B        C        D        E     a1234
3      4        B        C        D        E        F     b2345
4      5        B        C        D        E        F     b2345
5      6        C        D        E        F        G     c3456
6      7        C        D        E        F        G     c3456


Note that df.filter(regex=r"Column \d").columns.tolist() only works if your columns are as in the example dataframe (the word 'Column ' followed by a digit. You can also specify a list of column names like you did and the result would be the same: ['Column 1','Column 2','Column 3','Column 4','Column 5']

Did not work for me. Tried the exact same syntax as per the solution.

@HariShreyas Then your dataframe is different from the one in your question. I've edited the answer with the code to create the dataframe to make it more clear.
